# how to get print command in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

normally in c or c ++ we are using printf command for displaying values,but in salesforce which command we can use for displaying the data from the apex class.kindly let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

System.debug('some string'). See the [apex language reference](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/App_Logic) doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.debug('print content'); or 
you can also use in the controller: ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'print content')); and in the actual page use: apex:messages /

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How is your answer different to the other answer already posted? Please add more detail if you think it is a valuable answer.